# checking if data exist in mysql using entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity

i have a mysql database table . The tablename is Question and i have a column name questionNo under that table . i have a web form that consists of a create button and some textbox , so every time i click the create button , it will create question number 1 , 2 so on into the database... but if i refresh the page and create again , it will still start from 1 . how do i check from database from questionNo column under tablename Question , that there is already question 1 , 2 or 3 so on .. so the next question i create after clicking the create button will be +1 of the questionNo column . Sorry for my bad English . I am new to  entity framework , how to do this using entity ?

For example 3 rows of record with the questionNo 1 .. then when i create again , i might have 2 rows of record with questionNo 2 and so on . The problem now is that , after i refresh the page , i will be inserting multiple rows of record with questionNo 1 again

Comment: Please post your code.  It will help us significantly in understanding your problem

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You can create auto increment primary key for Question table as below

```
CREATE TABLE Question 
(
QuestionNo int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  // other fields 
PRIMARY KEY (QuestionNo)
)
```

MySql will do the increment when you insert new record, you don't need to handle it by the code

---

Using Entity Framework

If you want to get the current max value of QuestionNo

```
int maxQNo= context.Question.Max(q => q.QuestionNo);
```

check for `newQNo` already added like below

```
bool alreadyAdded= context.Question.Any(q => q.QuestionNo == newQNo);
```

Comment: yes but that will auto increment for every row . Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough , i have a  web form with a create button , i will be creating multiple rows of record for a question . So in my database , i will have multiple rows with the same questionNo.
For example 3 rows of record with the questionNo 1 .. then when i create again , i might have 2 rows of record with questionNo 2 and so on . The problem now is that , after i refresh the page , i will be inserting multiple rows of record with questionNo 1 again .

Comment: Hey , thanks for spending the time and effort helping but int maxQNo= context.Question.Max(q => q.QuestionNo); returns 0 hmmm

Comment: Sorry again , but is it possible to increase the value of questionNo?